# How to get starting and ending date from last year in plsql

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have a plsql function `count_order_cust` with three parameters. But `p_start` and `p_end` are optional. If I call function with three parameters, then function is executed well, but if I call function with one parameter `p_id`, then it has to count orders for last year (i.e. 01/Jan/2013 - 31/Dec/2013) and this is my problem. How can I do this?

Here is function `count_order_cust`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_order_cust(p_id f_customers.id%TYPE, p_sd f_orders.order_date%TYPE DEFAULT NULL, p_ed f_orders.order_date%TYPE DEFAULT NULL)
RETURN NUMBER IS v_count_orders NUMBER(3) := 0;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(cust_id) INTO v_count_orders
FROM f_orders
WHERE cust_id = p_id AND f_orders.order_date BETWEEN p_sd AND p_ed;
RETURN v_count_orders;
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN RETURN NULL;
END count_order_cust;
```

With this select I get date in last year, but I need have in p_sd = '01/Jan/2013' and in p_ed = '31/Dec/2013'.

```
select add_months(sysdate,-12) from dual;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code shows you how to derive the required dates, then bundle the code into functions which can be used as the default parameters of your procedure:

```
declare 

   function getFirstDayOfLastYear return date is   
   begin
      return trunc(add_months(sysdate,-12),'YEAR');   
   end;

   function getLastDayOfLastYear return date is   
   begin
      return trunc(sysdate,'YEAR') - 1;   
   end;

   procedure myProc(
       p_start date default getFirstDayOfLastYear, 
       p_end date default getLastDayOfLastYear
   ) is 
   begin
      dbms_output.put_line(p_start);
      dbms_output.put_line(p_end);
   end;


begin

  myProc;

end;
```